# A site that I have hosted is giving me a HTTP 448 error and I have no clue why

Tags: http, website, html5

I'm a rookie web developer and I have a pretty simple site that I hosted for free on infinityfree.net. I haven't visited the site or edited the code for at least a month, and everything was working just fine when I decided to take a break from working on it. But now when I try to visit the site URL I get a HTTP 448 error. I've googled the error code, but all I get is the phrase "Gone until you stop paying attention to people I dislike" with no more explanation. It's never been a problem until today, so could it be an issue with the host? I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Huh... that's a new one. According to [ietf.org](https://www.ietf.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml) 448 falls into an unassigned range (not found in any http standard or known to be used by any major http based api). Of course, it's rather trivial to implement custom http codes with most webserver but it's generally seen as bad form. Infinityfree claims to use Apache 2.4... which implements no such error code by default. You need to contact them and ask them "what the heck?"

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue today with my website but figured out what this actually means, in fact the error is given by the DNS webserver as the domain name subscription expired

Hope this would help!

Answer (score 1):

It could be a reference to the Murderbot novella [*Rogue Protocol*](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/9410546-there-needs-to-be-an-error-code-that-means-i), by Martha Wells.

> There needs to be an error code that means "I received your request but decided to ignore you."

While I don't think the book gives the error a numeric code, fans have assigned it [the number 448](https://worldbuildersmarket.com/collections/the-murderbot-diaries-by-martha-wells/products/murderbot-pin-murderbot-quote-448).

[image: pin badge with the words "448: I received your request but decided to ignore you."]

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the club )

According to [httpstatuses.com](https://httpstatuses.com/) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) there isn't 448 HTTP status code.
Seems like someone geek's humor. Maybe you should check the site for viruses.

BTW, there is a [decision chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Http-headers-status.gif)
 that shows how response codes are identified. Will be helpful if someone is trying to triage response codes issues.

[image]